# Best way to inject component in Spring with Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, inversion-of-control

For inject a beans with Spring/Kotlin, I know two ways :
Passing it into the constructor :

```
@Service
open class MyService @Autowired constructor(

        @Autowired
        val myRepository: MyRepository

)
```

Using the 'lateinit' keyword :

```
@Service
open class MyService {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var myRepository: MyRepository

}
```

I know the two works, but i'd like to know which one is the best ? Is there some problem I can encounter with one solution and not the other ?

Thank you !

Comment: http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer constructor. Spring no longer requires The @Autowired annotation if there is only one constructor. This way you don't have to make the class open (you do for some Spring things, like @Scheduled but that's another question) or use a var. It's also pretty easy to read.

This is all you need

`@Service
class MyService (private val myRepository: MyRepository)`